# module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xlabel'

Tags: python

`module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xlabel'` I have tried all methods listed in other post and they don't work

Please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EZyf.png)

I read all the similar questions about this error, they are either spelling mistakes or importing the `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` wrong.
I have tried different versions too
Also tried import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
and `matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel()` instead of `plt.xlabel`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vlfw.png)

Comment: What;s your *MatPlotLib* version? (`matplotlib._version.__version__`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in command prompt (windows):

py -m pip install --upgrade pip

py -m pip uninstall matplotlib

py -m install matplotlib

Answer (score -1):

By now I suggest you open at first your matplotlib.pyplot module and check if xlabel method is defined there. Maybe you happened to modify this script. It is quite easy - right click on the pyplot word and choose **go to definition** (at least it looks so in my IDE - VS Code). With shortcut keys **ctrl+f** type xlabel to see if it is mentioned anywhere in this script. If not, please uninstall matplotlib and install it again. If you type `pip install matplotlib` latest version will be installed. **What is relevant** is that you should make sure before running the script that interpeter from python you installed matplotlib to is chosen. I investigated all versions of matplotlib since 2.0.0 and each of them includes xlabel method.